# Why does Android Studio - Flutter keep getting stuck after making any change in pubspec.yaml in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am having some trouble with Android Studio and flutter. Every time I make a change in the pubspec.yaml file of my flutter app and save the change, then run my app in my phone, my computer gets stuck while building the app.

Its stucks while running gradle -> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

I am forced to restart my laptop and then run AS again. The app will now run in my phone but anytime I open pubspec.yaml and make some dependency changes, then my computer will get stuck again and I have to restart again.

Below are some details that might be helpful.

[image: Flutter version and ubuntu version]

I had tried the same with Ubuntu 18 and I was still getting a similar challenge.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the Operating System and reinstall it again afresh. I did not manage to get a simpler solution